# Unable to delete Exchange contacts via Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, microsoft365

I have some contacts that I cannot remove.  I don't know how they got in this state, or how to solve the problem.

If I use:

```
Get-Contact
```

The names are listed.  If I use:

```
Get-MailContact
```

They are not.  What this means is that

```
Remove-MailContact -Identity <blah>
```

Throws an error:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object '<blah>' couldn't be found on <exchange server>
```

If I inspect the problem contacts using:

```
Get-Contact -Identity <blah> | fl
```

I find that these values are the different ones

```
RecipientType            : Contact
RecipientTypeDetails     : Contact
```

Correct MailContacts have the value "MailContact" in these fields.

How can I delete these contacts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include [example] of your code, . See [ask]

Comment: I've tried to reformat - is that any better?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you pipe Get-Contact into Remove-MailContact?  For example, `Get-Contact -Identity <blah> | Remove-MailContact -Confirm:$false`